# Comparing strings in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a set of strings in a list, the list is given below in the code. I would like to compare each string to its previous strings. Obviously the first positioned string will not be compared with previous  string since there isn't any. The logic is basically:
2nd positioned string to be compared with 1st positioned string,
3rd positioned string to be compared with 1st and 2nd positioned string,
...
...

```
s = ["avocado", "banana", "carrot", "avocado", "carrot", "grapes", "orange"]
for i in range(2,len(s)):
    for j in range(i,2, -1):
        if s[i] == s[j]:
            print (s[i])
```

Now, if there is a match found, the string name with the positions will be shown. Such as `avocado found in position 4 and 1`.
I am stuck at this code. How should I proceed?

Comment: What would be the expected output for a list `["avocado", "avocado", "avocado"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
s = ["avocado", "banana", "carrot", "avocado", "carrot", "grapes", "orange"]
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    for j in range(i):
        if s[i] == s[j]:
            print(s[i])
```

You were close. Use `range(i)` to count from 0 to i. Use an index of 1 to get the second item in the list (lists start at 0).

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for this. I have a doubt though, the `range(i)` will this be compared to previous string or the whole list? For example, the 3rd positioned string "carrot" should be compared to its previous two strings instead of the whole list. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Yes. When i is 2 in the outer loop, j will loop from 0 to 1 (range is exclusive)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is that you could make a dictionary of the items to positions

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(s)):
    d[s[i]].append(i + 1) # '+ 1' since we count from 1-index

for item, positions in d.items():
    if len(positions) > 1:
        print("{} found at positions {}".format(item, positions))
```

Comment: The best solution of all the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fit a general use case:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','a','b','e','d']

for i in list(set(a)):
    b = [j for j, e in enumerate(a) if e == i]
    if len(b) > 1:
        print(i," found in positions:",b )
```

Output:

```
b  found in positions: [1, 6]
a  found in positions: [0, 5]
d  found in positions: [3, 8]
e  found in positions: [4, 7]
```

Comment: Hi Celius, thanks alot. I have a silly question. The code above starts to search from 0th position right? Since I want to search it from 1st position ('b'), shouldn't I be using `range`? Because the output I am getting starts from a: a  found in positions: [0, 5]
b  found in positions: [1, 6]
e  found in positions: [4, 7]
d  found in positions: [3, 8]

Comment: Yes, and no. Technically it uses the `set` of the list to find which items repeat more than once in the list `a`, scanning all of it (starting from position 0, till the last one). For those that do repeat more than once, we show the positions of those items. In your example you started from position yet you printed avocado found in position 0 and 3 (4 and 1 would be wrong because lists start from 0 not 1).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the thing is I do not want to search the entire list for each string. I only want to compare the previous strings for the current string. This is the logic I would like to apply.

Comment: What are you finally trying to achieve? Seems like a rather difficult way of achieve the same result?

Comment: Searching the complete list will take massive amount of time for each string. To reduce the search complexity I was trying to implement a logic where the current string will only be compared to its previous strings and if found at so and so positions. If the same string is repeated after 20th position, then we will have 3 matched strings output which will be printed after a while. But yea this was the logic.

Comment: Searching the strings before each position will take more time for big lists with repetitions, I can assure you that. If your list has 1M and 300k repetitions, and the repetitions are scattared all over the list up to the last position, then you will be searching the full list (because of the last repetition) + you would have searched the list (although not full) 299,999 times for the previous repetitions, whereas I would have searched it 1 time for the 1M entries.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. Can we improve your code to ignore the searching for the first string? So that the searching starts from 'b' which searches the whole list and so on to next string. I want to ignore the first string for searching for a task basically.

Comment: But if we do that, how could we find the first item? In your case avocado? It is easy to fix that, all we need to do is define `new_list = original_list[1:]` and search through the `new_list`

Comment: Sorry I was not clear by my words. What I meant was, can we start the comparison for strings from 'b' instead of 'a'. The string 'b' will be compared with the entire list, including the first positioned 'a'. and then 'c' will be compared in the similar manner.

Comment: Yes, we can `remove(original_list[0])` from the set, that means `a` will never be matched tho

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to determine the positions of all words, e.g. in a dictionary. Then you can print the words with positions:

```
from collections import defaultdict
positions = defaultdict(list)
s = ["avocado", "banana", "carrot", "avocado", "carrot", "grapes", "orange"]
for position, word in enumerate(s):
    positions[word].append(position)

for word, position in positions.items():
    print(f"{word} found at positions {' and '.join(position)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combinations function from itertools to efficiently go through all pairs:

```
s = ["avocado", "banana", "carrot", "avocado", "carrot", "grapes", "orange"]
from itertools import combinations
matches = [(w1,p1,p2) for (p1,w1),(p2,w2) in combinations(enumerate(s),2) if w1==w2]
print("\n".join(f"{word} found in position {p1} and {p2}" for word,p1,p2 in matches))


# avocado found in position 0 and 3
# carrot found in position 2 and 4
```

Comment: The formatting and use of f-strings is great! But, what if there are more than 2 matches?

Comment: Based on the OP's wording I assumed that each pair was to be reported separately (but only once per pair) which is this will do.  In any case, the `matches` variable would allow other usage/reporting types if needed.